# Predicting a random variable Y will increase within n minutes if random variable X increases

Tags: machine-learning, time-series

I am starting to learn machine learning and I would like advice of how to model that random measure *Y* will increase within n minutes if random measure X increases.

X and Y have different units (GBP and USD) so I am using returns (percentage change) to make them the same unit.

My data looks like this

```
Time, X, Y
00:00, 1%, 0%
00:01, 0%, 1%
00:02, 2%, 0%
00:03, 0%, 2%
```

Just from observing this data you can see that Y increases after one second after X increases but not sure the best way how to model this!

Comment: With only this few observations, nothing very general can be drawn. If you can tell that $Y(t) = X(t-1)$ just by having a quick look at your data, this is probably not a machine learning problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to look for lag effects - the easiest thing is to try a number of lag time windows and look at how they correlate with target. If you think there is a distinctive lag impact, then at some point the correlation strength should increase.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a "previousX" field. That will certainly  help. 
The only way i know to do this is to iterate through the whole dataset. If someone has an idea how to do this in a quicker way using numpy/pandas methods, please share.

Comment: I was thinking of doing that but that would only work if the lag was just 1 second. The lags could be longer than one second so would need to shift by n seconds.

Comment: I see. Then you can copy the whole dataset, then change the index field "Time" by as many seconds as you need, and then join them by Time field.